# upload multipart document on dropbox through API (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to upload multi part document on drop box using the ruby on rail api through.

```
def upload_passport
  APP_KEY = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
  APP_SECRET ='INSERT_APP_SECRET'   
  flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
  authorize_url = flow.start()
  file = open(params[:file])
  response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', file)
  puts "uploaded:", response.inspect
end
```

Comment: Add APP_KEY,APP_SECRET error:  dynamic constant assignment

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning values to constants, every time your method will run. This is not allowed in ruby.

```
 APP_KEY = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
 APP_SECRET ='INSERT_APP_SECRET'
```

You can add that in the class containing this method though:

```
class MyClass
  APP_KEY = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
  APP_SECRET ='INSERT_APP_SECRET'   

  def upload_passport
    flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
    authorize_url = flow.start()
    file = open(params[:file])
    response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', file)
    puts "uploaded:", response.inspect
  end 
end
```

Comment: i am resolve this problem like this:                                                                      app_key = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
app_secret ='INSERT_APP_SECRET'

Comment: I am require the  dropbox sdk but error throw                                                             require 'dropbox-sdk'       Error:(cannot load such file -- dropbox-sdk)

Comment: This answer is correct in what is solves the question. But assigning to a constant or var in this manner and only using it once has no benefit, just hard code the string in the call to `new`. But having secrets in code is generally bad practice, you could use secrets.yml (which is git ignored) to store the secrets: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml

Comment: i know  this is for only demo purpose.

Comment: app_key = '<%= ENV['APP_DROPBOX_APP_KEY_DEVELOPMENT'] %>' like this.